# Windows 8.1 Data usage

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, winsxs

The WinSXS folder on my PC currently holds over 6.9GB of data, which is a few hundred files inside the folder named like amd64microsoft-******.

I have read, and read but just can’t seem to find an trustworthy answer on the following questions:

- What does `MRT.exe` do?

Comment: Where is this `MRT.exe`? What’s your other question? And how does your question at all relate to the WinSxS folder?

Comment: MRT is the "Malware Removal Tool", as probably noted in the file's "properties" window.

Answer (score 0):

[Clean Up the WinSxS Folder](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251565.aspx):

> Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 automatically reduces the size
>   of the WinSxS...
>
> The `StartComponentCleanup` task was created in Windows 8 to regularly
>   clean up components automatically when the system is not in use. This
>   task is set to run automatically when triggered by the operating
>   system. When run automatically, the task will wait at least 30 days
>   after an updated component has been installed before uninstalling the
>   previous versions of the component.
>  If you choose to run this
>   task, the task will have a 1 hour timeout and may not completely clean
>   up all files...
>
> The `StartComponentCleanup` task can also be started from the command
>   line:
>
> ```
> schtasks.exe /Run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Servicing\StartComponentCleanup"
> ```

[`MRT.exe` (Windows **M**alicious Software **R**emoval **T**ool)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/890830)

> The Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool helps remove
>   malicious software from your computers that are running Windows 10
>   Technical Preview, Windows 8.1, ...
>
> Microsoft releases a new version of the Microsoft Malicious Software
>   Removal Tool every month. After you download the tool, the tool runs
>   one time to check your computer for infection by specific prevalent
>   malicious software (including `Blaster`, `Sasser`, and `Mydoom`) and helps
>   remove any infection it finds.

Next commands could help as well: `where mrt`, `mrt /?`, `mrt`. The last (`mrt` with no line parameter) launches the *Malicious Software Removal Tool* graphical user interface which could be informative enough...